# How can I make my video streaming faster?

Tags: html, video-streaming, swf, html5, m4v

I wonder how could I insert a high-quality video in my webpage providing fast downloading for my users.

I have a video which is around 80 MB large. It's two minutes long. I have it in M4V, OGG and MP4 format. When I try to lower the size of it, it lost its quality. If I keep the same size, the video is very slow in downloading. I have tried embedding with plain HTML5.

What can I do?

Comment: Hi, I have this video in three formats: m4v, ogg and mp4. I am embedding it with an html5 video tag. The video is 2 minutes long and its bitrate is 1000. I also provide an swf alternative for browser which are not supporting html5.

Comment: I'm on Windows XP

Comment: Is the video buffering completely before it's played, or is it stuttering? Can you try to use [qt-faststart](http://notboring.org/devblog/2009/07/qt-faststartexe-binary-for-windows/) on the MP4 file and see if that helps? Also, your file really is too big. How did you try to lower its size?

Comment: Hi, it stutters while loading. I was wondering how youtube could play very huge files in a very fast way, that's the way I would like to provide my video (but without using the youtube player)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are pretty much only 2 factors when it comes to download speed.

Your own maximum throughput and the maximum throughput of the other person involved in the transfer (and technically the maximum throughput of every single network device on the path between the two points).

So if your users generally are connected with bad speeds, decrease the file size, there is nothing else you can do to improve speeds. A decrease in file size will result in lower quality output. There is no magic involved.

If your server is connected to a line with horrible speed, move it to another hosting service that provides better speed. Or better yet, move to a [Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

If all of that is not acceptable, just upload to YouTube and embed it. They will convert your Video into several formats with several resolutions and offer the optimal solution to your client. No matter if they're on horrible mobile or satellite hookup.

Comment: I was wondering if I could create something in Youtube's style indeed

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, MP4 videos that last 2 minutes should only be around 15 - 30MB at the most. Give us some specs like

- resolution? = 480p
- frame rate? <= 24
- audio bit rate? (can usually be lowered a lot)
- what is your encoder?
- how fast is your internet? != dialup lol

Comment: good catch, bit rate of 1000 , 2 minutes, does not add up to 80meg , a MediaInfo viewer might come in handy to see the bitness. Mabey too many bits used up on some audio that might not be as nessisary.

Comment: Sorry I realized only in this moment that I typed bad with my numeric keypad! I meant 50 MB, exactly 50.644 KB.